# Why doesn't the TPL support state-filtered multi-task continuations?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

The TPL has a number of `TaskContinuationOptions` values that control what circumstances a task executes under. For example, `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled` prevents a task from running when its parent is canceled.

However, none of these task state filters apply to multi-task continuations. You can't do something like:

```
TaskFactory f = new TaskFactory();
Task t1 = new Task (() => Thread.Sleep (5000));
Task t2 = new Task (() => Thread.Sleep (4000));
Task t3 = f.ContinueWhenAll (new Task[] { t1, t2 },
                             (tasks) => { ... },
                             TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

You end up getting an error that says, `"It is invalid to exclude specific continuation kinds for continuations off of multiple tasks."`

What I don't understand is why this condition would be excluded from the API. Why wouldn't it be a perfectly valid use case to want a task to run only when all antecedents ended in a particular state?

Answer (score 0):

"...to run only when all antecedents ended in a particular state..."

Note your word "all", I'm not MS, but I'll bet it has to do with the fact that another whole `TaskContinuationOptions` enum would be needed that included `All`, `Any`, `OnlyOne`, `AllButOne` and so on and so forth.

Furthermore, Eric Lippert is always answering questions like these with "it's expensive and time consuming to add a "simple" feature.  Way moreso, than getting the basics right and letting users implement the rest.

Answer (score 0):

`ContinueWhenAll` means "run the continuation when all tasks have completed successfully". Specifying `NotOn*` or `OnlyOn*` would be either contrary or superfluous to that definition. See the remarks section of [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321525.aspx).